# Wix Toolset - URL shortcut using computer name and IIS web application alias

Tags: wix, wix3.11

So, I've been trying out Wix Toolset and stumbled upon a problem.

How do I add a url shortcut using computer name and IIS web application alias and/or port?

For example:

```
http://mycomputer/myapp
```

or

```
http://mycomputer:8080/myapp
```

or

```
http://mycomputer:8080/ (which points to an IIS web application)
```

I know how to add a URL shortcut to the desktop, but the problem is the URL I'm going to use. I've tried `<Property Id="APPURL" Value="http://[ComputerName]/myapp" />` and using the `APPURL` as the `Target` value of the shortcut, but the installer rolls back - it doesn't proceed with the installation so I'm assuming that it's wrong.

*Note: I've already tried harcoding a URL and it's working just fine.*

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work now. I'm posting this in case someone encounters the same problem.

```
<Property Id="APPURL" />
<SetProperty Id="APPURL" Value="http://[ComputerName]/myapp" Sequence="execute" Before="InstallInitialize" />
```

I've already tried this solution earlier but without the `Sequence="execute"` property so I was getting an error on `InstallInitialize`. So, yeah, the `Sequence`property solved it.

Hope this helps others.